# Add a vector<string> field to a cMessage

Tags: omnet++

I'm building a custom cMessage that includes vectors as some fields. I have no issue with `int` or `double` vectors, but with `string` vectors, I get an error. Below is a sample message definition to reproduce the issue.

```
cplusplus {{
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
typedef std::vector<string> StrVector;
}};

class IntVector { @existingClass; };
class StrVector { @existingClass; };

message sampleMessage extends cMessage
{
    IntVector SampleIntVector;
    StrVector SampleStrVector;
}
```

In my code, I have the below block

```
sampleMessage *msg = new sampleMessage();
vector<int> intVect = {1,2};
vector<string> stringVect;
string inputString = "dummy string";
stringVect.push_back(inputString);
msg->setSampleIntVector(intVect);
msg->setSampleStrVector(stringVect);
```

Using OMNeT++ version 6.0 pre10, at the 7th line, I get the error below suggesting the cMessage is expecting a `vector<char *>`

```
error: no viable conversion from 'vector<std::string>' to 'const vector<char *>'
```

I also tried on OMNeT++ version 5.6.2 and got a different error message. For clarity, the file *testModel_m.cc* is generated by OMNeT++.

```
testModel_m.cc:170:13: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')
        out << *it;
        ~~~ ^  ~~~
testModel_m.cc:2040:45: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator<<<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >' requested here
        case 1: {std::stringstream out; out << pp->getSampleStrVector(); return out.str();}
                                            ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6416:5: note: candidate function [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
    operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
    ^
testModel_m.cc:158:22: note: candidate function [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const T&) {return out;}
```

If I change the vector to `char *`, it works, but for my use case, I would need a vector of `string` since I search for values in a vector and with `char *`, that doesn't work quite well.

Is there a way to have a `vector<string>` field as part of the custom cMessage?

Comment: What version of OMNeT++ do you use?

Comment: I am using version 6.0 Preview 10.

Comment: I installed version 5.6.2 and got a different error. Updated the question with the error related to the each tested OMNeT++ version.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for the error `use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous` is adding own definition of `operator<<` inside `cplusplus {{ }}` block, for example:

```
cplusplus {{
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
typedef std::vector<std::string> StrVector;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const StrVector& vec) {
    std::stringstream out; 
    for (auto i : vec) {
        out << i << ", ";
    }
    return os << out.str();
};
}};
    
class IntVector { @existingClass; };
class StrVector { @existingClass; };

message sampleMessage {
    IntVector SampleIntVector;
    StrVector SampleStrVector;
}
```